# Unity UI Input Field suddenly malfunctioned

Tags: unity

I'm using Unity 5.0.1f1, and my UI Input Fields are not working as they are supposed to.

I have an Input Field that is placed in a Panel and inside a Canvas.
It has a Text component in which I can set text that the Input Field will display.
When I change value of this Text component, the changes are not reflected on the Input Field, it seems to be reset to the value of Input Field (Script) \ Text of the Input Field.

If I enter Play mode, I can input text normally but when I build and run on my Android phone, I cannot input anything.

Has anyone encountered this problem? How can I solve this?

[image: text field malfunctioned]

Answer (score 1):

The children of the InputField GameObject are modified as needs be by the scripts that make the InputField work (you'll notice a input caret child appears at runtime too and as you say the text attribute of the child is overwritten).

If you need to set a default value for the text there is a field in the inspector of the InputField Component on the parent InputField GameObject; underneath the "navigation" attributes, there is a reference to the "Text Component" of the child and a field which says "Text", add your text here.

I'm not an android developer so I've no idea how to fix the second part of the problem.